# What are the impacts of the @ServiceDependency annotation

Tags: java, annotations, osgi

What are the impacts of the **`@ServiceDependency`** annotation on a method?

I'm trying to study some sample code that I downloaded, and in it there is a method that is annotated with `@ServiceDependency`. The method never gets called anywhere else. So, I'm guesing that the `@ServiceDependency` annotation makes a method run automatically. What does this annotation really do, because some member variables in some classes are annotated with `@ServiceDependency`.

```
class UI {

    private final Map<ServiceReference, AppScreen> screens = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    @ServiceDependency(removed = "removeScreen")
    public void addScreen(ServiceReference<?> sr, AppScreen screen) {
        if (tabPane != null) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> {
                // Do something
            });
        }

        screens.put(sr, screen);
    }

    public void removeScreen(ServiceReference<?> sr) {
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            AppScreen remove = screens.remove(sr);
            // DO something else
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This annotation is not from OSGi, but from a Felix subproject, "DependencyManager". It's one of many projects that help to manage osgi services. In OSGi, with "Declaratives Services", this annotation is called `@Reference`.

In your example, when an instance of `AppScreen` is registered into the OSGi Registry, then the method `addScreen` is called. When this instance is unregistered, the method `removeScreen` is called.

See the documentation for [DependencyManager](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-dependency-manager.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can I have more than one method annotated with `@ServiceDependency`?

Comment: Yes, It's possible